# DBus Error: Unable to append with type error saying list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbus

I write a dbus program with Python using package `dbus`.

```
@dbus.service.method("com.fsevenm.castboard.KaroWidget", in_signature='', out_signature="a{si}")
def get_screens(self):
    return [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
```

I am sure the type and the signature are correct but each time I call the method it gives this error in the console:

```
ERROR:dbus.service:Unable to append ([{'id': 1}],) to message with signature a{si}: <class 'TypeError'>: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

The response of dbus:

```
('g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.TypeError: '
 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n'
 '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 751, in '
 '_message_cb\n'
 '    _method_reply_return(connection, message, method_name, signature, '
 '*retval)\n'
 '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 254, in '
 '_method_reply_return\n'
 '    reply.append(signature=signature, *retval)\n'
 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list\n'
 ' (36)')('g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.TypeError: '
 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n'
 '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 751, in '
 '_message_cb\n'
 '    _method_reply_return(connection, message, method_name, signature, '
 '*retval)\n'
 '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 254, in '
 '_method_reply_return\n'
 '    reply.append(signature=signature, *retval)\n'
 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict\n'
 ' (36)')
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended the [dbus-python example service](https://github.com/zyga/dbus-python/blob/master/examples/example-service.py) to have a list of dictionaries like you were trying to do.

I think you were missing an `a` for the array and then a second `a` for the dictionary.

The following worked for me:

```
@dbus.service.method("com.example.SampleInterface",
                     in_signature='', out_signature='aa{si}')
def GetArrayDict(self):
    return [
            {"first": 1},
            {"second": 2}
            ]
```